# unauthorized using curl php

Tags: php, macos, http, curl, unauthorized

I am using curl but facing unauthorized error even though the username and password set are correct.

```
$login=base64_encode(sprintf('%s:%s',$this->user,$this->password));
$curl_url = $this->url;
$query= "";

$headers = array(
            sprintf('Authorization: Basic %s',$login),
            sprintf('Accept: %s',$this->format),
            'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            sprintf('Content-Length: %d',strlen($query))
            );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$curl_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($query));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        $exec = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

URL: `"http://localhost/ariaconfig/rest/app_settings_v3/?app=3&os=ios&ver=2.0.1"`

**The code is working perfectly fine in Windows but not in OSX**

Comment: Looks ok, I'd suggest doing a `print_r($headers)` to make sure values are all as expected. No need to set Content-Length manually; cURL does that for you.

Comment: @miken32: The header look fine : 
`Array
(
    [0] => Authorization: Basic bXR2bjpCaXpUM2No
    [1] => Accept: JSON
    [2] => Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [3] => Content-Length: 0
)`

Also, the same code is working fine in Windows. I am using OSX.

Comment: You aren't doing any error checking on your curl code. What if `$exec` is false? How can you get the errors?

Comment: @miken32: I am sorry but what exactly you mean by error checking. If i do a var_dump($exec), I get 'string(12) "Unauthorized" '.